# Questions, Statements or Mix in a Wizard

Tags: wizard, questionnaire

I'm creating a wizard for a flow to apply to a job, and this consists of about 10 screens. So, my question is, on each screen, which is the best UX?

- Phrase every heading as a question (for instance, "How long have you had a driver's license?"
- Phrase every heading as a statement (for instance, "Your driver's licence experience"
- Mix and match whenever you feel like it, ie it doesn't matter.

In my world it seems simpler and less cognitive load to be consistent in the phrasing so you have to think less, and a question (even though it results in more text) seems clearer to answer than a statement.

But I'd love inputs and studies on this.

Answer (score 2):

Just a humble input, not study. You are right that cognitive load should be minimal so this results in more reliable information from user. In general question is better because user have to mentally transform statment to question and then answer it.

But you may see that web forms (and not only) are mostly made with short labels and not with questions. This is not only because of lack of place. The main reason is to ask as most as exact what you need. For example, to answer your question *"How long have you had a driver's license?"* (suppose in years) user need to remember year when ne obtain his license and than make ariphmetic calculation. This is a kind of brain loading. The statement  *"Your driver's licence experience"* is not also one step in thinking - are you about date of formal license receiving or about real practical experiense? Also user are guessing why are you asking so he may provide unreliable answer. And if you write *"Your  driver's license issue year:"* probably you'll receive concrete answer and more important - you can check it as well as make all needed calculations by yourself correctly in the future as you need not to link user's data with the date of asking.

But in some cases you should ask the question and then prompt the statement you provided in very long questionnary to test if user provide you with correct information.

Comment: Wow, great reply. And surely does makes sense. But how about mixing, so if one wizard step there's a question, in the other a statement, then statement, then question. Would this create some negative effect compared to keeping it congruent?

Comment: I think the main source of negative effect will be not meeting user expectations. I mean if user fills out a questionnaire he probably expects questions. When user set up new application or OS he expects statements. When user fill out form of application for loan he expects labels. Sorry but this is still only IMO.

Comment: Well, doesn't answer the question entirely, but it's a great point. The expectations is really the main thing as you say. So, I'm thinking, maybe it doesn't matter that much - instead of focus on consistency, focus on what a user expects.